# Get element by tag and class

Tags: javascript

I have a script

```
var firstImg = row.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
```

and later

```
if (x){ firstImg.src='/images/checked.png'; }
```

I'd like to define that the img should be of `class='something'`

(Get first img with class='something')

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use the

```
 querySelectorAll('img.classname')[0]
```

this returns first image with class set to class name. However jQuery is better!!

```
$('img.classname')
```

Comment: If you are just looking for the first element you can just use `querySelector('img.classname')` btw.

Comment: that's how i did
`var firstImg = row.querySelectorAll('img.check')[0];` Thanks all!

Answer (score 9):

Just set it...

```
firstImg.className += "something";
```

...or...

```
firstImg.classList.add("something");
```

If you can get away with not supporting older browsers.

[Further Reading](http://blog.alexanderdickson.com/manipulating-classes-with-javascript) (disclaimer: link to my own blog).

If you're intending to *get* elements with a certain class name, you can use...

```
document.getElementsByClassName("something");
```

...or...

```
document.querySelectorAll(".something");
```

Keep in mind `getElementsByClassName()` isn't in <= IE8.

You can use...

```
var getElementsByClassName(nodeList, className) {
    var i, results = [];
    for (i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
        if ((" " + nodeList[i].className + " ").indexOf(" " + className + " ") > -1) {
             results.push(nodeList[i]);
        }
    }

    return results; 
}
```

Of course, it's super simple if you're using jQuery...

```
$(".something");
```

Answer (score 2):

this selects the first `img` with class='something':

```
var firstImg = $('img.something')[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you could not throw away the old browsers, then you need a loop.

```
var imgs = row.getElementsByTagName('img'),
    some_class = 'something',
    i, first_img;

for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    if ((' ' + imgs[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + some_class + ' ') > -1) {
       first_img = imgs[i];
       break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let img = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("someclass")).filter(a=>a.tagName=="IMG")[0];
```

Comment: the code looks ok, but it is deprecated to answer without explanation